# Plot shows up as blank output line

Tags: plotting, warning-messages, output

Let me start by saying this is NOT one of a thousand duplicates of the function not showing up on the plot. Mathematica has been working fine for the last 2 years, and then all of a sudden, `Plot` stopped showing anything at all. Here is a picture of what I'm on about.

[image: Plotting with no output]

If I then type `Show[%1, ImageSize -> Medium]`, the plot sometimes shows up as usual, but it doesn't always work, and even if it did (call me spoiled), I don't really want to have to do that every time I need a plot.

Here's the play-by-play of what happened:

1. I was doing homework, plots were fine.
2. Mathematica 11.1 crashed.
3. I opened it back up, and angrily went to settings to configure autosave
4. When I tried to plot again, it wouldn't show up.
5. I reset default settings, still broken.
6. I uninstalled and updated to v11.3, still broken.
7. I rebooted my computer, still broken.
8. I made an account here, and am now begging for your help.

Honestly, what has baffled me most of all is number 6. How can the problem persist after uninstalling and reinstalling a different version?

One more thing that may be useful (or may not), here's the first cell that it broke on:

```
γ[τ_] := 2/Δω E^(-(2/Δω + I ω0) τ)
sig[τ_] := 1 + Re[γ[τ]]
Plot[sig[τ] /. {Δω -> 0.1, ω0 -> 1}, {τ, -100, 100}]
```

I don't think there's anything too unconventional in there, but maybe I'm missing something. Using the `Show[%, ImageSize -> Medium]` method here doesn't work.

Anyway, please help.

Update: The problem is happening with any graph I try to plot, not exclusively the two examples that I've shown. Also, I've tested a few different things and it's not just `Plot`. It does the same thing with any type of plot (`LogPlot`, `ListPlot`, etc) as well as any type of `Graphics`.

Comment: Have you considered getting in touch with Wolfram Support as well?

Comment: That's a good idea. I usually try to avoid support services like the plague, but I guess I could swallow my pride. Thanks for the edits, too!

Comment: Look at the range of `LogPlot[sig[\[Tau]] /. {\[CapitalDelta]\[Omega] -> 1/10, \[Omega]0 -> 
    1}, {\[Tau], -100, 0}]`. `Plot` apparently chokes on trying to deal with this range of values.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really an answer, but more a query about how accurately the code appearing in the question represents the functions given in the homework assignment.

Are you sure the definitions you give are exactly correct? As copied from your post, `sig` is highly oscillatory. It also has a huge range for negative values of `τ`. Here is a plot made by choosing the parameters carefully and restraining the interval over which `τ` varies.

```
γ[τ_] := 2/Δω E^(-(2/Δω + I ω0) τ)
sig[τ_] := 1 + Re[γ[τ]]
Plot[sig[τ] /. {Δω -> 10, ω0 -> 1}, {τ, -10, 20}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plot]